# YouTube API v2 results are not in chronological order

Tags: request, youtube-api

I'm using now YouTube api v2.
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=30&start-index=1&orderby=published&v=2

Why results are not ordered in the way specified in request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are not ordered because Youtube API v2 has a problem with orderby. Although it is mentioned for years, it has never been fixed in API v2 as you can see in [issues with gdata](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2894).
However, I strongly recommend you to use Youtube API v3.